# Why can't I access chat with 25 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, chat

I am a quite new user with 25 reputation and would like to ask some additional questions about C in the chatroom. You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk there (see FAQ). When I searched for similar questions, a few brought up that I should bring this to a dev's attention.

Answer (score 11):

You got an upvote 12 minutes ago, so now you have 25 rep, but rep on your chat profile is cached for some time so it's still 15 there; after an hour, I believe it will be updated on chat.SO, and then you'll be able to post messages.